# gRPC Sessions: Lifecycle And Persistence

Tags: networking, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc, grpc-python

I have implemented a gRPC Server to delegate tasks from a client process to this server.

Considering multiple clients I wonder if the Servicer-Class is transient or permanent.

I derive the servicer as follows:

```py
class MyServicer(my_pb2_grpc.MyServicer):

    def __init__(self):
        self.attrA = 0
        self.attrB = 0
        self.attrC = 0

    def rpcMethodA(self, request, context):
        self.attrA += 1
    def rpcMethodB(self, request, context):
        ...
```

The server starts like

```py
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor())
my_pb2_grpc.add_MyServicer_to_server(MyServicer(), server)
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50000')
server.start()
```

As shown, `MyServicer` has attributes per instance. Is that object maintained ? Will `attrA` be incremented for that one instance of the servicer class which is called by one specific client ?
Will there be multiple instances bound for each client ?
How long will that instance exist ? Is it re-created on each new call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From testing the behaviour, the gRPC Servicer exposes this behaviour:

**Sessions**: No session management.

**Servicer Lifetime**: The servicer instance persists up to server termination.

The derived servicer is used for every client connecting to the server. The attribute `attrA` will be incremented as long as the server runs.